# multiple Makefile for a single project

Tags: makefile, mingw, gnu-make

I am trying build a project with several modules included. the file tree looks like this:

[image]

the individual Makefiles for lib_one, lib_two and Main.cpp works fine, generating the 2 DLL and the EXE for the project, but requires enter at each directory and execute the command 'make' for each module.

I want now a Makefile in the top level directory ('/project') which triggers the building for all the other modules (DLLs and EXE) once. Based on some search results I got something like that:

```
lib_one := ./src/lib_one
lib_two := ./src/lib_two
libraries := $(lib_one) $(lib_two)
player    := ./src

.PHONY: all $(player) $(libraries)
all: $(player)

$(player) $(libraries):
        $(MAKE) --directory=$@

$(player): $(libraries)
```

when I execute the command 'make' I got this error:

```
Makefile:10: ***.  Stop.
```

(the line 10 is this one: `$(MAKE) --directory=$@`). Besides a way to fix this error, I am looking to a way to accomplish this 3 things:

1)
 the object files (`*.o`) from all the modules (DLLs and EXE) should be stores on a directory `build` in the same place from the directory `src`.

2)
the final files (`*.dll` and `*.exe`) should be placed in a directory `reelease` alongside the directories `src` and `build`.

3) if item 2 was possible, would be nice if each type of file being placed in a specific directory inside `release` (`bin` for `*.exe`, `lib` for `*.dll` and `shared` for other types). also, even with the exe and dlls in different directories, would be possible run the executable from this directory (making it search for the necessary libraries in `../lib` alongside the other usual places?).

Comment: Make sure you use tab character rather than spaces to indent the recipe lines. The code you posted contains spaces.

Comment: This non-recursive makefile may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953668/412080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Maxim is likely right for the cause of the error -- spaces vs tabs.  As far as a your other questions go, without using non-recursive make, you could do something like:

Makefile:

```
export base_dir := ${CURDIR}
export obj_dir := ${base_dir}/build
export release_dir := ${base_dir}/release   

lib_one := ${base_dir}/src/lib_one
lib_two := ${base_dir}/src/lib_two
libraries := $(lib_one) $(lib_two)
player    := ${base_dir}/src

.PHONY: all $(player) $(libraries)
all: $(player)

$(player) $(libraries): | ${obj_dir} ${release_dir}
        $(MAKE) --directory=$@

$(player): $(libraries)

${obj_dir} ${release_dir} :
        @mkdir -f $@
```

The sub-makefiles would have access to any exported variable from the parent (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html)), so in these you could do stuff like:

```
${obj_dir}/%.o : %.c
       @echo  compiling "$^ ==> $@"
       $(CC) -c -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

which would compile the objects to the right directory.

Beware though -- if you have two components that produce an object file with the same name, because they're being produced in the same directory, you will end up with a potentially hard to debug race condition.   Typically each component produces object files in its own unique directory to avoid this very thing.

Comment: Ok, I think this will work, but now it's not creating the directories `build` and `release` if not exists. Is it possible do that automatically?

Comment: `$(player) $(libraries): | ${obj_dir} ${release_dir}` (note that these must be [order-only](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) prerequisites).   Then do `${obj_dir} ${release_dir}: ; mkdir -f $@`.