# How to make an object file in a different folder with c++ and a makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

When I run my code I get the error

```
g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -I -o obj/main.o -lm
g++ error: obj/main.o: No such file or directory
makefile:21: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

In my file structure I have a folder with everything in it so I am trying to make some subdirectories and organize everything a little bit. I am trying to get the object file (main.o) to go into an obj folder instead of staying in the base folder as it currently is.

I can't figure out what is going wrong in my makefile and can't find where some of this is being executed and am extremely new to c++ and make. My code is pasted below.

```
IDIR=../include
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -I

LDIR = ../lib
ODIR= obj

LIBS = -lm

_DEPS = add.h multiply.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %, $(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = main.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %, $(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

main: $(_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o$(OBJ) $(LIBS)




.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

I haven't read any specific documentation as I have been teaching myself by simply searching the internet for tons of small bits from many different sources. I am using Windows 10 with visual studio code as my compiler and make g++ as my make utility. I apologize for commenting on my own question as this is my first time using Stack Overflow and didn't know I could get in trouble for commenting. I am sorry for causing a mess.

Comment: On which operating system and with which compiler? If on Linux, read about [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). Use builtin make rules (try `make -p`). See also [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) that you would use with `-x`. For a simple program like yours, having a subdirectory for object files is against the habits.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and using visual studio code.

Comment: I never used Windows, and probably never would (I am 60 years old, and coding since 1974). So I cannot help you. I do recommend to read documentation, and at least the wikipage about [make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)). If your compiler is [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org), read about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) and enable all warnings and debug info (so `g++ -Wall -g`)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953668/412080

Comment: Without additional details (what OS, what compiler, what `make` utility....), and mention of previously read documentation, your question is too broad. So I voted to close your question. Feel however free to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59652796/edit) your question to improve it. Don't comment your own question please.

Comment: If your `make` utility is a variant of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) be sure to **read the [documentation of GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)**. It is written in English, and IMNSHO well written. If your `make` utility is unrelated to GNU make, find its documentation and read it. The GNU `make` utility [understands](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/307472/40065) `make --version` and `make --help`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g++ -c -o obj/main.o main.cpp
```

you must provide the path for the output file

Comment: I strongly recommend using `g++ -Wall -g -c -o obj/main.o main.cpp` to get debug information and warning

Comment: I know this is almost certainly a stupid question but this is my first exposure to make and c++ so how would  I provide the path?

Comment: @Addison Higgins: What documentation did you read? The URL of the documentation that you did read should appear in your question