# Makefile: Separated sources and objects

Tags: c, makefile, directory-structure

I've been trying for some time to separate the source files of my project from the generated object files.

Indeed, I would like my project to be structured this way:

```
obj/
    main.o
    src1.o
    [...]
src/
    main.c
    src1.c
    [...]
Makefile
```

The Makefile I currently have is as follows:

```
NAME                =       a.out

OBJ_DIR             =       "obj"
SRC_DIR             =       "src"

MAIN_SRC            =       main.c

PROJ_SRC            =       src1.c      \
                            src2.c      \
                            src3.c

MAIN_OBJ            =       $(MAIN_SRC:%.c=%.o)

PROJ_OBJ            =       $(PROJ_SRC:%.c=%.o)

CC                  =       gcc
RM                  =       rm -rf

$(NAME):            $(MAIN_OBJ) $(PROJ_OBJ)
                    $(CC) $(MAIN_OBJ) $(PROJ_OBJ) -o $(NAME)

all:                $(NAME)

clean:
                    $(RM) $(MAIN_OBJ) $(PROJ_OBJ)

fclean:             clean
                    $(RM) $(NAME)
```

I tried to use [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html), without success.

```
MAIN_OBJ            =       $(MAIN_SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

PROJ_OBJ            =       $(PROJ_SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

[...]

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o:     $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
                    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Does anyone have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MAIN_SRC` and `PROJ_OBJ` do not have directory prefix, so that expressions

```
$(MAIN_SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
$(PROJ_SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
```

do not replace anything.

Fix:

```
MAIN_OBJ := $(MAIN_SRC:%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
PROJ_OBJ := $(PROJ_SRC:%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
```

And then your pattern rule should work.

You may like to have `make` create that `$(OBJ_DIR)` for you:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(OBJ_DIR) :
    mkdir -p $@
```

---

[A more advanced example for you with automatic header dependency generation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953668/412080).

Comment: Thank you for your response.

The solution works if I replace `$(SRC_DIR)` by `src` in the pattern rule.

Indeed, if I leave `$(SRC_DIR)`, I get the following error: `make:  *** No rule to make target '"obj"/main.o', needed by 'a.out'.  Stop.`

Is there any way I can use a variable instead of `src`?

EDIT: I just found the problem, I removed the quotation marks in the variable `SRC_DIR`

Comment: @MrSquaare Remove quotes from `"src"` and `"obj"`, they are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

bro!

If your project "`main`" 's architecture is just liking this:

```
main

|

|__Makefile

|__obj

|__src

     |__main.c
 
     |__src1.c

     |__src2.c

     [...]
```

Just add this to your "`Makefile`" to store your object out of source files directory:

```
# Object files
# String substituion for every C/C++ file
# e.g: ./src/src1.cpp turns into ./obj/src1.o
OBJS := $(patsubst %.c, ${OBJ_DIR}/%.o, $(notdir $(SRC_DIR)))
```

And just add this to your "`Makefile`" to compile:

```
# Compile: Generate object files from source files
# $@ := {NAME}
# $< := THE first file
# $^ all the dependency
# C Sources
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

END!