# Compiling files resides outside of source directory using Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have directories structure like,

```
                                                    |
                                                    |
                                   ------------------------------------
                                   |                                  |
                              directory 1                        directory 2
                                   |                                  |
                             -------------                      -------------
                             |           |                      |           |
                      directory 1.1  directory 1.2          Makefile   directory 2.1
                                         |
                                       file.c
```

In above hierarchy, How to compile file.c using Makefile(resides in directory 2)?

Comment: Where do you want the object file to go?

Comment: You can adapt [this makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953668/412080) for your targets.