# Makefile that makes the object files in different directories

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to organize the files of my project, as all of them are in the root directory, and change the Makefile, as it is too long and very repetitive. So I make the following 3 directories:

- include : Contains all of the .h files
- src : Contains all of the .c files
- obj : It is empty for the moment but after compilation, it will contain all of the .o files

So my first goal was to make the .o files and put them in the /obj directory and the Makefile I made is the following :

```
#paths
INCLUDE = include
SOURCE = src
OBJS = obj

# compiler
CC = gcc

#flags
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -pedantic -I$(INCLUDE)
VFLAGS = --leak-check=full -v

OB = $(OBJS)/space.o $(OBJS)/command.o $(OBJS)/screen.o $(OBJS)/graphic_engine.o $(OBJS)/game.o $(OBJS)/object.o $(OBJS)/player.o $(OBJS)/game_reader.o $(OBJS)/die.o $(OBJS)/set.o $(OBJS)/inventory.o $(OBJS)/link.o $(OBJS)/game_loop.o

build: $(OB)

$(OBJS)/%.o: $(SOURCE)/%.c $(INCLUDE)/%.h
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

When I run it, all the .o files are made and placed in the obj directory but the last and I get the folloing error :
`make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/game_loop.o', needed by 'build'.  Stop.`

In the OB variable, I changed the position of the game_loop and noticed that the previous .o files were made and the compilation stopped again at the game_loop file.

> I want help to overcome this error and help to continue making the
>   Makefile

Comment: If just `obj/game_loop.o` is not built, then there is no `src/game_loop.c` or no `include/game_loop.h`. -- BTW, read Make's manual and learn about `VPATH` and `$(NAME:pattern=pattern)`.

Comment: @thebusybee  You are right, there is no game_loop.h file in the project. Thanks for the advice,  I will look it up !!

Comment: @thebusybee  Also, can you suggest a way to write the OB variable in a better/cleaner way ??

Comment: A working example for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953668/412080