# Multi target makefile with subfolders

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

My project has the following structure:

```
\---Project
    +   Makefile
    |
    +---source
    |   +---target1
    |   |       t1_lib.c
    |   |       t1_main.c
    |   |       
    |   +---target2
    |   |       t2_lib.c
    |   |       t2_main.c
    |   |       
    |   \---common
    |           common_lib.c
    |
    +---headers
        +---target1
        |       t1_lib.h
        |       
        +---target2
        |       t2_lib.h
        |       
        \---common
                common_lib.h
```

I am trying to write a makefile which allows me to run 'make target1' or 'make target2' and compile target1 source code with common source code or compile target2 source code with common source code respectively.

In my project, target1 is call 'ue' and target2 is call 'enb'.
This is what I have in my current makefile:

```
# Author: j0lama

# COMPILER
CC = gcc

#FLAGS
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -ansi -g -std=c99 -D_DEBUG

#LIB FLAGS
LIBFLAGS = -lgc -rdynamic -lcrypto -lpthread

#LINK FLAGS
LINKFLAGS = -lsctp

# PATHS
UE_SOURCE_DIRECTORY = source/ue/
UE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY = headers/ue/
ENB_SOURCE_DIRECTORY = source/enb/
ENB_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY = headers/enb/
COMMON_SRC_DIRECTORY = source/common/
COMMON_HDR_DIRECTORY = headers/common/

OBJECT_DIRECTORY = objects/
BUILD_DIRECTORY = build/

COMMON_CFILES= $(wildcard $(COMMON_SRC_DIRECTORY)*.c)
COMMON_OBJECTS= $(patsubst $(COMMON_SRC_DIRECTORY)%.c, $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)%.o, $(COMMON_CFILES))

CFILES = $(COMMON_CFILES)
OBJECTS = $(COMMON_OBJECTS)

all: clean ue enb

ue: setup_ue $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY) $(TARGET) ue_emulator

enb: setup_enb $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY) $(TARGET) enb_emulator

setup_ue:
    $(eval CFILES += $(wildcard $(UE_SOURCE_DIRECTORY)*.c))
    $(eval OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(UE_SOURCE_DIRECTORY)%.c, $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)%.o, $(wildcard $(UE_SOURCE_DIRECTORY)*.c)))
    $(eval INCLUDE_DIRECTORY = $(UE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY))

setup_enb:
    $(eval CFILES += $(wildcard $(ENB_SOURCE_DIRECTORY)*.c))
    $(eval OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(ENB_SOURCE_DIRECTORY)%.c, $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)%.o, $(wildcard $(ENB_SOURCE_DIRECTORY)*.c)))
    $(eval INCLUDE_DIRECTORY = $(ENB_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY))


$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY):
    @mkdir $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)
    @echo "Building objects directory..."

ue_emulator: $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Building $@..."
    @$(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBFLAGS) $(LINKFLAGS) -o $@

enb_emulator: $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Building $@..."
    @$(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBFLAGS) $(LINKFLAGS) -o $@

$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)%.o: $(SOURCE_DIRECTORY)%.c $(COMMON_SRC_DIRECTORY)%.c
    @echo "Building $@..."
    @$(CC) -I $(COMMON_HDR_DIRECTORY) -I $(INCLUDE_DIRECTORY) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBFLAGS) $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @echo "Removing objects files"
    @rm -rf $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY) $(TARGET)
```

Somehow this makefile does not compile any file.

Comment: Working example for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953668/412080

Comment: You can debug your makefile with the options `-d` and/or `-p` given to Make.

Comment: I'm sorry to have to tell you this, but you are trying to write a sophisticated makefile when you haven't yet mastered the basics. You must start smaller, and work on simpler exercises awhile.